# e2e Testing bootstrap select picker

Tags: protractor, bootstrap-selectpicker

bootstrap selectpicker generates some elements so that protractor has to click a button to show the list of options (that are in the hidden select) and then click the item in the list. I'm having trouble figuring out, by text which list item needs to click.

Sample HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <button type="button">
        <div class="ripple-container"></div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox">
            <li data-original-index="1"><a>Male</a></li>
            <li data-original-index="2"><a>Female</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <select>
        <option> </option>
        <option value="MALE">Male</option>
        <option value="FEMALE">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to be able to tell protractor to click the li that corresponds to the option with the value `FEMALE` - because of localization, I don't want to hardcode strings, but rather find out the position of the option with the value `FEMALE` and use that to select the `<li data-original-index="2">`

Is this even possible? Is there another, better way to do it?

Comment: Can you just set the value of the hidden select? Or if you want to click, how about cssContainingText?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm new to e2e testing, I feel like I should be clicking the buttons, no? EDIT: Setting the value of the hidden select might work, but I feel like I'd just be "getting away with it"